# Issues with Multiple PHP variables in an SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

My problem is i am trying to get 3 variables from the URL, they echo the correct information so i know that my $_GET's are working fine, The first $SC1 and $SC2 both work fine but the 3rd one in the SQL statement Dosnt.

If i replace

```
$thestatement = ("SELECT * FROM asset_records  WHERE a_catagory = '".$SC1."' AND ".$SC2." = '". $SC3 ."' ");
```

with

```
$thestatement = ("SELECT * FROM asset_records  WHERE a_catagory = '".$SC1."' AND ".$SC2." = 'apple' ");
```

it works fine but i know $SC3 = apple because i can echo the variable and its apple, please help im pulling my hair out. Heres the rest of the code regarding this.

Note: This is a search function that basis itself on which link people click in my websites menu and takes into consideration when people first click on the website so it displays all items in it.

```
require ('..\connect_db.php') ;

$SC1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sc1']); echo $SC1; 
$SC2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sc2']); echo  $SC2;
$SC3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sc3']); echo $SC3;


if ($SC1 && $SC2 && $SC3 = '') {

$thestatement = ('SELECT * FROM asset_records');}


else  {;

$thestatement = ("SELECT * FROM asset_records  WHERE a_catagory = '".$SC1."' AND ".$SC2." = '". $SC3 ."' ");

}

$result = mysql_query('' .$thestatement. '') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: semicolon after your `else {`

Comment: Use prepared statements for pete's sake, or you're going to get SQL injected.

Comment: if ($SC1 && $SC2 && ($SC3 == '')) {

Comment: @danishan echo $thestatement and run Query in Sql

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_` functions and not `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: Hi Dan the ; didnt actully effect the script, didnt even flag an error.

Comment: Do you mean this? `($SC1 == '' && $SC2 == '' && $SC3 == '')` or were you checking boolean of the `$SC1` & `$SC2`. Either way you need to use the comparison operator (`==` or `===`) not the assignment operator (`=`). You are currently emptying `$SC3`.

Comment: @JackWilliams  Cheers Jack, Im simply asking the question of, if SC1,SC2,SC3 all equal nothing then display all results. if they equal something then put them into a SQL statment. Im new to php but im learning at a fast pace, im making an application that will be useful to me and im currently not caring about SQL injections as its only ran on my local machine but thats something i will look at after i finished playing. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, I'm learning constantly here too. The code I left in the above comment will check that SC1, 2 AND 3 are empty. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are emptying $SC3 in the if condition.

Comment: $SC1 && $SC2 && $SC3 == '' needed a double ==, Thanks

Comment: @JackWilliams are you a stack overflow police man I just helped a guy who was pulling his hair.

Comment: It's an opinion and @HaRsH already established the point you've made in the comments. You just rehashed what he said.

Comment: @JackWilliams I answered before his comment. That's why my answer was selected. Or we could have answered at the same time. Or stack exchange android app is bit slow